# how to create phonegap brightness plugin for Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

As I have found out there is no way to change the device brightness using Phonegap, so I have decided to create this plugin by my self. I am new to Phonegap and I do not know is it hard or not.
I have red some examples on how to create plugins for Phonegap But there are some things I don't understand. 
I have this code for changing the screen brightness and I want to create a method for Phonegap that calls it:

```
private void setBrightness(int brightness) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
    layoutParams.screenBrightness = brightness / 100.0f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
}
```

is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's pretty easy to do if you follow the [plugin development guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide). For what you want to do it would be like this:

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/brightness", 
  function(require, exports, module) {
    var exec = require("cordova/exec");
    var Brightness = function () {};

    var BrightnessError = function(code, message) {
      this.code = code || null;
      this.message = message || '';
    };

    Brightness.CALL_FAILED = 0;

    Brightness.prototype.set = function(level,success,fail) {
      exec(success,fail,"Brightness", "set",[level]);
    };

    var brightness = new Brightness();
    module.exports = brightness;
});
```

Then you'll need to write some Java code to do the phone call. You'll need to create a new class that extends the Plugin class and write an execute method like this:

```
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
    PluginResult.Status status = PluginResult.Status.OK;
    String result = "";

    try {
        if (action.equals("set")) {
            int brightness = args.getInt(0);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
            layoutParams.screenBrightness = brightness / 100.0f;
            this.cordova.getActivity().getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
        }
        else {
            status = PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION;
        }
        return new PluginResult(status, result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
    }    
}
```

Whatever you call this class you'll need to add a line in the res/xml/config.xml file so the PluginManager can create it.

```
<plugin name="Brightness" value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.Brightness"/>
```

and finally in your JavaScript code you'll need to create they plugin and call it like this:

```
function panicButton() {
    var brightness = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/brightness");
    brightness.set(50);
}
```

That should about do it.